# python polymorphism with Tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, polymorphism

I’m new to OOP programming and I’m trying to understand polymorphism in Python, all the tutorials that I find online seem very ambiguous, like this one: [How does polymorphism work in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835793/how-does-polymorphism-work-in-python), it helps me understand the idea of polymorphism, but how do I then apply this to Tkinter, or other modules.
Can someone please give some good examples of polymorphism in Tkinter with clearly explained comments.

-Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Polymorphism is a somewhat polymorph concept in CS. When it comes to OO, it mainly means 'polymorphic type-based dispatch', which means that the concrete implementation of a method / resolution of an attribute will be selected at runtime based on the object's type. As an example:

```
class Foo(object):
    def do_this(self):
        return 42

class Bar(object):
    def do_this(self):
        return 84

def whatever(*objects):
    for obj in objects:
        print obj.do_this()

objects = [Foo(), Bar()]
whatever(*objects)
```

The point is that I can now create a new class:

```
class Baaz(object):
    def do_this(self):
        return -1
```

and pass it to `whatever()` without having to modifiy `whatever()`:

```
whatever(Baaz())
```

`whatever()` works with any object having a `do_this(self)` method, and the correct implementation of `do_this()` is automagically selected by being looked up on the object itself.

Compare this with pure procedural code:

```
def foo_do_this(foo):
    return 42

def bar_do_this(bar):
    return 84

def whatever(*objects):
    for obj in objects:
        if obj.__class__.__name__ ==  "Foo":
            print foo_do_this(obj)
        elif obj.__class__.__name__ ==  "Bar":    
            print bar_do_this(bar)
        else:
             print "dont know how to handle '%s', sorry" % (obj.__class__.__name__)
```

which requires that I edit `whatever()` to accomodate any new implementation of `xxx_do_this()`.

And no, this isn't a "good example of polymorphism **in Tkinter**, because I never use Tkinter - but if you understand the above example you should be able to spot quite a few examples of polymorphism in Tkinter as well as in almost any Python module or package.

Comment: good examples of polymorphism *in Tkinter*

Comment: cf my last paragraph.

Comment: For a beginner, tkinter is a bit more complicated than typical class inheritance examples as it is neccesary to create a Tk toplevel widget, an application mainloop and other stuff specific of the GUI framework.

Comment: Note that there's no inheritance involved in my example...

Comment: oh right (although your classes inherit from object), I was refering to typical examples of OOP in general terms