# Python polymorphism to replace if/elif/elif

Tags: python, polymorphism

From the ["Fluent Python" book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920032519.do), it says:

> *However, even with ABCs, you should beware that excessive use of
>   isinstance checks may be a code smell—a symptom of bad OO design. It’s
>   usually not OK to have a chain of if/elif/elif with insinstance checks
>   performing different actions depending on the type of an object: you
>   should be using polymorphism for that—i.e., designing your classes so
>   that the interpreter dispatches calls to the proper methods, instead
>   of you hardcoding the dispatch logic in if/elif/elif blocks.*

Now, there are many SO questions on how to replace if/elif/elif blocks, and a lot of answers are using dictionaries etc etc. But it's not what the paragraph suggesting

> *designing your classes so that the interpreter dispatches calls to the proper methods*

Does it mean the following approach?

```
class Artist:
    def draw(self): ...

class Gunslinger:
    def draw(self): ...

class Lottery:
    def draw(self): ...
```

The dispatcher just calls:

```
def draw_dispatcher(obj):
    obj.draw()
```

Are there any other ways?

Comment: Yes and yes. (But why the extra `draw_dispatcher` function, when `obj.draw()` suffices?) I'm not sure if this Q is too broad or not... or a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835793/how-does-polymorphism-work-in-python).

Comment: @cfi the `draw_dispatcher` was just demonstrating dependency injection.